# How to modify the code in which we have to find Peak element?

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures

i have a task in which i have to code a program to **find a peak element in an array**. I did code it, but when i showed it to my teacher she told me it wasn't accurate, even tho it was running fine on Dev C++.She told me to modify it. Can someone tell me, whats wrong with the code and how do i modify it.

```
int main(){
    int arr[50];
    cout<<"Enter size:";
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Elements:";
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(arr[i]>arr[i+1] && arr[i]>arr[i-1]){
            cout<<"PEAK: "<<arr[i]<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First thing to fix:  If `i` is `0`, what does `arr[i-1]` give you?

Comment: It didnt show any error..so i thought it might take a garbage value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies within second `for` loop body.
As NathanOliver pointed out in the comments, the `arr[i] > arr[i-1]` shall try to access memory at invalid offset when `i` is equal to 0. 
The same goes for the other condition - `arr[i] > arr[i+1]` would result in access out of bounds - well, your `arr` can hold a maximum of 50 elements, so if `n` is lower than 50, you should only access uninitialized memory.
The peak-finding condition could be rewritten as:

```
for (unsigned i = 0u; i < n; i++){
    bool isPeak = true;
    if (i > 0 && arr[i] < arr[i - 1]){
        isPeak = false;
    }
    if (i < n - 1 && arr[i] < arr[i + 1]){
        isPeak = false;
    }
    if (isPeak){
        std::cout << "PEAK: " << arr[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```

This exploits the *short circuiting* of logical operators - expressions are evaluated left to right, therefore - if we come back to `i > 0 && arr[i] < arr[i - 1]` condition - potentially dangerous check (that might result in invalid access) will not take place if the first condition (`i > 0`) is false.

As for the code itself, it now checks each side of the current element separately.

An ever better thing to do (although probably not related to what your teacher means) would be to use `std::vector`. The code could then handle more than 50 elements.

Comment: Thanku very much...what does i=0u means in ur code?

Comment: This is a minor thing, you could just as well write `int i = 0` or `int i = 0u`. 
`u` at the end of numeric literal means that this literal (0 in this case) is of type `unsigned`. If you used `0`, it would be of type `int` by default.
For more information, see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal
For your first coding exercises it does not really matter. It might make a difference if you rely on automatic type deduction. `auto foo = 0;` defines `foo` as `int`, whereas `auto foo = 0u;` would give you `unsigned foo`.

Comment: thanku, even tho m 4th semester computer systems engg student i feel like i donno shit bout programming,,Can u tell me how to improve my coding?

Comment: This is outside of the scope of this question, but I've found programming challenges sites like HackerRank or Codewars (which is the one I've used extensively, although it's quite slow sometimes) to be quite a good way to improve. You might also want to try out other programming languages if you feel like you are struggling with C++ (especially since it might be taught the hard way at university). It really depends on what you like to do - overall just keep practicing. Starting your own personal project is also a good way to come across new challenges & have fun. Good luck!

Comment: great, will do that,

Comment: great, will do that,